# Showing the TinyMCE controls only when the user edits the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have `textarea` control and I'm using TinyMCE library to add content editing functionality to this `textarea`.

Initially when the page is loaded, the *textarea* will not have any additional formatting controls. But when the user clicks on the *textarea*, the tinyMCE controls should be added to the textarea.

I was able to make that happen using this JQuery code:

```
$("textarea").focus(function(){
  $(this).tinymce();
});
```

But the problem starts when I want to hide the control when the user moves out of the textbox. I couldn't figure out a way to associate a `blur` event handler to this textarea because tinyMCE replaces my textarea with an iframe and the formatted content inside.

Is there anyway to show the tinyMCE control only when the user edits the content and hide them when the user leaves the editing area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `$(this).tinymce();` only once (the first time the textarea gets the focus).
The second time it gets the focus you should call

```
tinyMCE.get(editorid).show();
```

[To hide the tinymce](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aAPI/tinymce.Editor/hide) and show the textarea you should call

```
tinyMCE.get(editorid).hide();
```

You can call this when i.e. when the parent document gets the focus.

```
$(document).focus(function(){
  tinyMCE.get(editorid).hide();
});
```

Comment: how do i get the editor id? Is it the ID that I give to my textarea?